# how to debug error in running docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I have built a docker image on Windows Docker-desktop by using given Dockerfile from the link
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Docker-for-Microservices-with-Python/tree/master/Chapter06/thoughts_backend/docker/app

```
########
# This image will compile the dependencies
# It will install compilers and other packages, that won't be carried
# over to the runtime image
########
FROM alpine:3.9 AS compile-image

# Add requirements for python and pip
RUN apk add --update python3

RUN mkdir -p /opt/code
WORKDIR /opt/code

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base gcc linux-headers postgresql-dev libffi-dev

# Create a virtual environment for all the Python dependencies
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv
# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install and compile uwsgi
RUN pip3 install uwsgi==2.0.18
# Install other dependencies
COPY ThoughtsBackend/requirements.txt /opt/
RUN pip3 install -r /opt/requirements.txt

########
# This image is the runtime, will copy the dependencies from the other
########
FROM alpine:3.9 AS runtime-image

# Install python
RUN apk add --update python3 curl libffi postgresql-libs
# Copy uWSGI configuration
RUN mkdir -p /opt/uwsgi
ADD docker/app/uwsgi.ini /opt/uwsgi/
ADD docker/app/start_server.sh /opt/uwsgi/

# Create a user to run the service
RUN addgroup -S uwsgi
RUN adduser -H -D -S uwsgi
USER uwsgi

# Copy the venv with compile dependencies from the compile-image
COPY --chown=uwsgi:uwsgi --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
# Be sure to activate the venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy the code
COPY --chown=uwsgi:uwsgi ThoughtsBackend/ /opt/code/

# Run parameters
WORKDIR /opt/code
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/bin/sh", "/opt/uwsgi/start_server.sh"]
```

Building docker image is also successful.

```
> docker build -f docker\app\Dockerfile --tag thoughts-backend .
[+] Building 4.4s (24/24) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.65kB                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.9                                                                                                                                               4.1s
 => [compile-image  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.9@sha256:414e0518bb9228d35e4cd5165567fb91d26c6a214e9c95899e1e056fcd349011                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 27.70kB                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  2/10] RUN apk add --update python3 curl libffi postgresql-libs                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  3/10] RUN mkdir -p /opt/uwsgi                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  4/10] ADD docker/app/uwsgi.ini /opt/uwsgi/                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  5/10] ADD docker/app/start_server.sh /opt/uwsgi/                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  6/10] RUN addgroup -S uwsgi                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  7/10] RUN adduser -H -D -S uwsgi                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  2/10] RUN apk add --update python3                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  3/10] RUN mkdir -p /opt/code                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  4/10] WORKDIR /opt/code                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  5/10] RUN apk add python3-dev build-base gcc linux-headers postgresql-dev libffi-dev                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  6/10] RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  7/10] RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  8/10] RUN pip3 install uwsgi==2.0.18                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image  9/10] COPY ThoughtsBackend/requirements.txt /opt/                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [compile-image 10/10] RUN pip3 install -r /opt/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  8/10] COPY --chown=uwsgi:uwsgi --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image  9/10] COPY --chown=uwsgi:uwsgi ThoughtsBackend/ /opt/code/                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime-image 10/10] WORKDIR /opt/code                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:4d0b692e66d99d8df303ae457ee7569e080f864afef064f2c440f72b67e26da2                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/thoughts-backend
```

However, when I try to run/start docker image, it fails. I am not even login and access its terminal. How to debug a docker process when you can not even login to that, and it fails during startup?

```
> docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000/tcp thoughts-backend
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 2:
Caught SIGTERM signal! Sending graceful stop to uWSGI through the master-fifo
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 9: }
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 10:
: invalid signal specificationap: line 11: SIGTERM
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 12:
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 13:
: not foundstart_server.sh: line 14:
/opt/uwsgi/start_server.sh: wait: line 17: Illegal number: 9
```

Comment: Hi, can you list files in /opt/code plz ?

Comment: How can I list the /opt/code dir when I can not even start the docker container? I can not even login. This is what my main problem is.

Comment: Ok, I got it. When I run   "docker run -it <image-name> /bin/sh"   it does not fail, and I get interactive shell. Then I see that /opt/uwsgi/start_server.sh is in windows format instead of Unix, which is why it is failing. Then I execute running docker in root mode on another PowerShell terminal using   docker exec -it --user root 30aba94d8feb /bin/sh  here I replaced windows format file to Unix by converting in notepad++. Now the web server is running. However, python flask app is not starting due to import error